# Select dropdown menu item without value using webbrowser in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I have the following dropdown list, but I can't find a way to choose one of these options using webbrowser control in vb.net, because it doesn't have value.

```
<select name="month">
            <option>01</option>
    <option>02</option>
    <option>03</option>
    <option>04</option>
    <option>05</option>
    <option>06</option>
    <option>07</option>
    <option>08</option>
    <option>09</option>
    <option>10</option>
    <option>11</option>
    <option>12</option>
  </select>
```

How can I select one of these using the webbrowser?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it. :)

```
Dim element As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("select").Cast(Of HtmlElement).First(Function(el) el.GetAttribute("name") = "month")
        element.GetElementsByTagName("option").Cast(Of HtmlElement).First(Function(el) el.InnerText = "06").SetAttribute("selected", "selected")
```

Thanks anyway guys.